# Problem with ubuntu touch lg l40

Tags: ubuntu-touch

When I try to install Ubuntu touch on my smartphone and I enter :

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
```

it shows

```
2015/09/29 16:58:09 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/09/29 16:58:09 Device is |W3_GLOBAL_COM|
Device W3_GLOBAL_COM not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu
```

Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

your device is not an officially supported device, and thus it does not have an image in the image server.

In https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices you can find a list with the devices that have at least a port, but as long as I could see your device doesn't have one yet, unfortunately.